# jQuery mouseover event on image.Advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm new to jQuery. 
I'm trying to add a mouseover event to an image which changes the image and a mouseout event which sets the image back to original.

I have an image

```
<div id="enter">
    <img src="images/entersite.png"/>
</div>
```

and some jQuery code

```
$("#enter").mouseover(function(){
  $("#enter").html("<img src='images/entersitehover.png'/>");
});
$("#enter").mouseout(function(){
  $("#enter").html("<img src='images/entersite.png'/>");
});
```

I want to add the event to the image element rather than the div.
I was reading something like `$(:last:image)` to select last image(as it is the last image I thought this would work).

Any help would be great?

Or if you can point me to a decent tutorial I will learn myself?

Comment: you can do it like @lonesomeday answered, but if you want a simple mouseover/out image change, i would recommend you to use plain CSS (ex. #element:hover {}) instead of javascript, it is much faster
(see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175385/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-do-a-css-rollover)

Comment: @egyedg: thats a good comment. The only reason I'm using jquery is to play around with it as I'v never used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very simply with the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) function, which has two arguments: a function for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`. You can also select the `img` element within `#enter` using a descendant selector.

Finally you can directly set the `src` property of the `img` element.

```
$('#enter img').hover(function(){
    this.src = "images/entersitehover.png";
}, function(){
    this.src = "images/entersite.png";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any good tutorials/api's out there that you know of? Id love to learn more.